# Windows 10 Mobile change tile icons

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia-950-xl, personalization

I have just recently gotten a Lumia 950 XL. This is my first attempt of utilizing the windows mobile market.

I had to download a [third party app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/client-for-hangouts/9nblggh6ghbm) in order to make use of Google Hangouts. This works acceptably, but I do not like the icon used at all. Is it possible to change this tile icon to an image of my choosing?

Also, I've had to make a bookmark shortcut on the Start screen for the [Dashlane web interface](https://www.dashlane.com/app/#signin) since there is not Dashlane app for windows mobile. I would like to be able to change this bookmark's icon as well. I did try 2 of those "bookmark tile creator"s on the store, but they don't seem to work.

Comment: Try https://www.microsoft.com/pt-pt/store/apps/transparent-tile-pack/9wzdncrdpzq3 , but it might not have the app you want

Answer (score 1):

Try an app called "Pin it!", it will change the web page link, but I haven't found anything to change application tiles yet.